# What would be the time complexity if a recursive function is inside a loop?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recursion, loops

I am confused in calculating the time complexity for a recursive function inside a loop.

```
Function (int n){
   if(n<=1) return;
   for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
       Function(n/3);
   }
```

in the text book answer written for this is theta(n). Please explain how is it so?

Comment: Just use [the usual stuff](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis). What specifically have you tried and where did you get stuck? Hint: unroll the loop (but count its cost).